# Subversion Get Text Status Data in Python Commit Hooks

Tags: python, svn

I'm looking for a way to extend Python Commit Hooks such that I can ONLY find out all the files that were modified excluding all the revision properties changed.

Is there a SVN.Core or SVN.fs or another SVN import lib function that I could use?

I'm currently looking into
svn_fs_txn_prop

but haven't had much luck.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Subversion Core library in Python you can create a class to read through different Subversion Properties associated with a commit.

you can call something like:

```
changeCollector = svn.repos.ChangeCollector(self.fs_obj,self.fsroot,self.pool);

        for path, change in changeCollector.changes.items():
            # this is the property that i want
            change.text_changed
```